# How to make dplyr::filter from vector work in Shiny app

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have the following Rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap 
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

sidebarPanel( textInput("flowers", "flower name(s)", "virginica, setosa") )
mainPanel(
  renderPrint({
   flower_list <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(input$flowers, ",")[[1]], tolower))
   dat <- iris %>% filter(Species %in% flower_list)
   unique(dat$Species)
  })



)

```
````

Basically what it does is to take input from user and return list of
names after filtering. But it seems that it doesn't work:

[image]

For example the main panel should return two values `virginia setosa`.
What's the right way to do it?

In console it works fine:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
dat <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species %in% c("virginica","setosa"))
unique(dat$Species)
#> [1] setosa    virginica
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Comment: `strsplit(input$flowers, ",")[[1]]` This only takes the first element of your vector after string splitting with delimiter `,`. try removing `[[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the space between `virginia` and `setosa` in `sidebarPanel( textInput("flowers", "flower name(s)", "virginica, setosa") )`. You can either remove the space or remove the white spaces by modifying your code with something like this:

`flower_list <- trimws(unlist(lapply(strsplit(input$flowers, ",")[[1]], tolower)))`

Answer (score 1):

As there is only a single string, after splitting we get a `list` of `length` 1.  It can be converted to a `vector` by extracting the first element (`[[1]]`)

```
flower_list <- tolower(strsplit(input$flowers, ",\\s*")[[1]])
```

In addition, we also changed the `split` pattern by using a regex to match zero or more space (`\\s*`) after the comma (`,`)

With this change, the dashboard looks like

[image]

The output can be made to appear in the same order as in the `textInput`

```
 mainPanel(
   renderPrint({
    flower_list <- strsplit(input$flowers, ",\\s*")[[1]]
    iris %>% 
      filter(Species %in% flower_list) %>%
      mutate(Species = factor(Species, levels = flower_list)) %>%
      .$Species %>%
      levels
   })
 )
```

### [image]

In the OP's post, as the other answer mentioned, we get a leading space for `' setosa'` and it will not match when we are doing an exact match in the `filter`.  The `tolower` is only required if the input string can have uppercase letters.  In the example, it was not the case, so can be omitted.